# Perdite/perdita en ŝiaj/siaj pensoj…

Tags: pronouns, participles, pronoun-si

Mi volas diri frazon kiel la jenan:

> Joan, perdite en siaj pensoj, forgesis ŝlosi la pordon.

Tamen mi hezitas pri la vortoj *perdite* kaj *siaj*.

Se mi bone komprenas, en ĉi tiu okazo oni povas uzi [participon kiu finiĝas per *-e*](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/participoj/e-vortoj.html#i-c5l) ĉar ĝi estas kroma ago kiu priskribas la subjekton. Tiuokaze, mi hezitas inter *sia* kaj *ŝia*. Mi supozas ke oni devus pensi pri la subjekto de la kroma ago *perdi*. Se mi provus diri ĝin kiel du frazopartojn, eble ĝi estus:

> Joan estis perdita en siaj pensoj kaj ŝi forgesis ŝlosi la pordon.

Tio pensigas min ke en la unua frazo la vorto devus esti *sia* ĉar ĝi estus tiel en la plena frazo. Ĉu tio estas ĝusta?

Mi provis serĉi similajn ekzemplojn en la Tekstaro kaj trovis la jenan:

> Tamen, perdita en siaj halucinaj vizioj, la franca prezidanto alvokas la junularon…

Tiu ekzemplo uzas *perdita* anstataŭ *perdite*. Ĉu ankaŭ en mia frazo tiu vorto estus pli bona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pri la vortoj *siaj* kaj *ŝiaj*:

*Joan, perdite en **siaj** pensoj, forgesis ŝlosi la pordon*. Temas pri la pensoj de Joan.

*Joan, perdite en **ŝiaj** pensoj, forgesis ŝlosi la pordon*. Temas pri la pensoj de alia virino.

La samo validas se en la frazoj oni uzas *perdita* anstataŭ *perdite*.

Por plia klarigo vidu: PMEG - [11.6.1. Si en simplaj frazoj](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/pronomoj/si/simplaj_frazoj.html).

---

### Pri la vortoj *perdite* kaj *perdita*:

> PMEG - [28.2. Participoj kiel E-vortoj](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/participoj/e-vortoj.html)
>
> > Participo kun E-finaĵo montras kroman agon, kiu rilatas al la subjekto
> >     de la frazo. Anstataŭ diri du frazojn, unu por ĉiu ago, oni kunmetas
> >     la frazojn al unu

Laŭ PMEG la frazo *Joan, perdite en siaj pensoj, forgesis ŝlosi la pordon* estas du frazoj en unu:

1) *Joan forgesis ŝlosi la pordon*

2) *Joan estis perdita en siaj pensoj*.

> PMEG: [28.1. Participoj kiel A-vortoj](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/participoj/a-vortoj.html)
>
> > Participo kun A-finaĵo prezentas agon aŭ staton kiel priskribon.

Laŭ tio, en la frazo *Joan, perdita en siaj pensoj, forgesis ŝlosi la pordon*, oni priskribas la agon aŭ la staton de Joan, alivorte ĝi donas informon pri kia estas la ago aŭ la stato de Joan.

Laŭ mia kompreno, la diferenco inter *perdite* kaj *perdita* en ĉi tiu frazo, estas eta nuanco apenaŭ grava por la fina signifo:

*Joan, **perdite** en siaj pensoj, forgesis ŝlosi la pordon*. Oni emfazas, kiel (=kiamaniere) Joan forgesis ŝlosi la pordon. Ŝi forgesas ŝlosi ĝin dum ŝi estas perdita en siaj pensoj, dum ŝi estas distra, malatenta, pensante pri aliaj aferoj. **La ago forgesi okazas en la sama momento en kiu ŝi estas malatenta, sed oni ne scias ĉu ŝi jam estas malatenta antaŭ la ago okazas**.

*Joan, **perdita** en siaj pensoj, forgesis ŝlosi la pordon*. Oni emfazas, kia estas (la menso-stato de) Joan kiam ŝi forgesas ŝlosi la pordon. **Ŝi jam estas en malatenta stato antaŭ kaj dum la ago okazas**.

Answer (score 1):

La du frazoj bonas, sed la signifo estas malsama:

```
Joan, perdite en siaj pensoj, forgesis ŝlosi la pordon.
```

*Perdite* estas adverbo, ĝi rilatas la manieron, *kiel* ŝi forgesis ŝlosi la pordon. Oni povas imagi ŝin rigardante forforen dum ŝi plu marŝas, sen atenti pri la pordo. *Perdite en siaj pensoj* estas respondo por kiel ŝi forgesis tion. Pensu pri jena frazo: *perdite en siaj pensoj, ŝi mispaŝis*.

```
Joan, perdita en siaj pensoj, forgesis ŝlosi la pordon.
```

Tie ĉi la fakto, ke li estas perdita en siaj pensoj, estas iel la *kialo* de la ago "forgesi ŝlosi". Do, *perdita en siaj pensoj* estas respondo por *kial*.

Pri *siaj*, laŭ mi estas tute trafa *ŝi (estis) perdita en siaj pensoj*. Do la pensoj apartenas al la subjekto, tial *siaj*.

Answer (score 0):

Laŭ mi, en via frazo ***perdita* ja estus pli bona** ol *perdite*.

Kial? Ĉar tiu participo ne temas pri *kiel*<sup>1</sup> Joan forgesis ŝlosi la pordon, sed ja temas pri *ŝia stato* dum ŝi forgesis tion. (Implicita ankaŭ pri *kial* ŝi forgesis ĝin, sed via frazo ne eksplicite esprimas tion. Se vi volas eksplicite esprimi tion, uzu *"ĉar"*, *"tial"* aŭ *"pro"*.)

Mi kredas, ke se vi uzas *perdita*, *siaj* estas ĝusta, kaj *ŝiaj* malĝusta, sed mi ne certas. Ĝi verŝajne similas al uzi *si* en pasiva frazo. (Vidu subsekcion "*Si* en pasiva frazo" en [sekcio "*Si*"](https://lernu.net/eo/gramatiko/pronomoj#si) de la ĉapitro "Pronomoj" de la gramatiko de lernu.net.)

<sup>1</sup>Oni ja ankoraŭ ne bone scias, kiel forgesi (nek memori) "funkcias", ĉu?